# Ambari FileView cannot open or upload files "Unauthorized connection for super-user"

Tags: hdfs, ambari

Having problems uploading or opening files in Ambari (v2.7.3) FileView (HDP v3.1.0). Getting error

Unauthorized connection for super-user: root at

[image]

I configs that I think are relevant here are:

```
hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.groups=*
hadoop.proxyuser.hdfs.hosts=*
hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups=*
hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts=hw001.co.local
```

Have seen similar questions here (https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unauthorized-connection-for-super-user/m-p/10211...) but not sure the problems are totally analogous.

Anyone know how to fix or get more debugging info?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at more existing post [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Unauthorized-connection-for-super-user-root-from-IP-192-168/m-p/193467#M155531) and [here](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/File-View-Error-Unauthorized-connection-for-super-user-root/m-p/145021#M107593) found that also needed to change

```
hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts=*
```

Setting this in HDFS configs in ambari and restarting the required services seems to have fixed the problem.

---

Could anyone help explain this config a bit more or link to docs explaining exactly what it does / means (ie. I hope it does not imply that root / super-user privileges are conferred to other users accessing HDFS in any way)? Found the docs here (https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/Superusers.html). Not much experience with HDFS admin, but

> In other words super is impersonating the user joe

gives me some concern about security. Could anyone help allay these concerns?